# Provide access to Azure Sql from vnet only

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

I've got vnet in Azure 10.1.0.0/24. VM connected to vnet directly by static ip: 10.1.0.5 and has not public endpoint. I connect to vnet using VPN and able to connect to VM. That wokrs fine.
I'd created Azure Sql database and want to limit connection only from vnet 10.1.0.0/24 (no public endpoint). So, my VM should be able to connect to Azure Sql and I shoul be able to connect to it when connected through VPN.
How can I configure this?

Comment: If you want to connect Azure SQL database via  VPN, you can use Azure private link service ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview

Comment: That's ok. I need to confure Azure Sql firewall to allow only vnet connection, but it isn't works for me.

Comment: Azure sql does not have private ip. So we need to use the service to assign private IP to sql. Then we can use VPN  to connect sql

Comment: So and how can I configure it?

Comment: Regarding how to configure it, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-portal

Comment: Do you have any questions about the reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you have set up a private connection to Azure – via P2S VPN, S2S VPN, or Express Route, then you can use a **TCP proxy server** to forward traffic to the public IP address for SQL Database because the virtual network rules are not supported VPN scenario, read the [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview#limitations) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/da8da34a-ad48-43a4-a070-311036e23675/exposing-azure-sql-server-through-vpn-connection).

[image]

**Main Steps**:

- You can add Azure VM vnet&subnet to virtual network rule on SQL Database as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview#azure-portal-steps)
- Download Nginx and change only the body the `nginx.conf` file without modifying headers to forward any traffic received on port 1433 to your SQL Database server `sqlserver.database.windows.net:1433`.

You could read [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/using-a-tcp-proxy-to-connect-to-sql-database-over-vpn/ba-p/390962) for more details.